# Sencha Touch 2 & webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch

Tags: css, sencha-touch

Has anyone had any luck with working out a solution to get *-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch* to work in Sencha Touch 2?

Although the performance is quite good on iPhones, Sencha's scroller is still too choppy on Android Phones. Meanwhile the CSS3 Solution would seem to be the choice to go for now on Android.

Anyone any luck?

Comment: As ilija mentions below, the new property is only available on iOS5 on iPhones. Even if/when it does come to Android, you'll have their fragmentation to deal with: Meaning most Android users won't see the feature for quite some time after it drops. Have you tried Sencha Touch 2? The Android performance has been vastly improved-

Answer (score 4):

To apply native style scrolling to a panel given as;

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        style: 'overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;',
        id: 'scroll-panel',
        items:[...]
});
```

overwrite touch move event to prevent Sencha Touch to control over scrolling on that panel

```
    var scrollPanelDom = Ext.get("scroll-panel").dom;
    scrollPanelDom.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);
```

so you can get rid of choppy scrolling and have it native style instead on IOS devices (and according to my tests better scrolling experience on Android devices)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, -webkit-overflow-scrolling is exclusive to Mobile Safari on iOS 5 and later. So no Android anyway.